# How to update xml node(web resource) value from crm plugin and save it?

Tags: c#, asp.net

i have a xml web resource in crm and have created a plugin for both reading and writing the xml data.now problem is that i am able to read that node value but cannot modify that node value?can anybody help me please,i am new to stack overflow ,thanks in advance?

Answer (score 0):

To modify the node value you need to set the InnerText property of the Node.
From what i know this will do the change in-memory.
You'll have to save the xml that is in-memory into a file and replace the old file.

Hope it helps!